# Calculations in dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe,

```
Check In Date   Check Out Date  Number  stage
2020/5/22 16:23 2020/5/22 18:39 1         a
2020/5/22 22:41 2020/5/23 2:03  1         b
2020/5/23 2:04  2020/5/23 2:04  1         c
2020/5/23 2:04  2020/5/23 2:56  1         d
2020/5/23 2:56  2020/5/23 2:56  2         a
2020/5/24 8:39  2020/5/24 8:39  2         b
2020/5/24 8:40  2020/5/24 10:58 2         c
2020/5/24 10:59 2020/5/24 10:59 2         d


df = pd.DataFrame({'Check In Date': ['2020/5/22 16:23', '2020/5/22 22:41', '2020/5/23 2:04', '2020/5/23 2:04', '2020/5/23 2:56', '2020/5/24 8:39', '2020/5/24 8:40', '2020/5/24 10:59'],
                   'Check Out Date': ['2020/5/22 18:39', '2020/5/23 2:03', '2020/5/23 2:04', '2020/5/23 2:56', '2020/5/23 2:56', '2020/5/24 8:39', '2020/5/24 10:58', '2020/5/24 10:59'],
                   'Number': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
                   'stage': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']})
```

I am trying to do some calculation in the dataframe like this:

```
          1       2
a -> b  4:02:00 5:43:00
b -> c  0:01:00 0:01:00
c -> d  0:00:00 0:01:00
```

Which equals to

```
                         1                                       2
a -> b  b: ckeck in date - a: check out date    b: ckeck in date - a: check out date
b -> c  c: ckeck in date - b: check out date    c: ckeck in date - b: check out date
c -> d  d: ckeck in date - c: check out date    d: ckeck in date - c: check out date
```

I check example related to pandas and dataframe, but I still don't know how to achieve this. Any thought?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) for shifting columns `stage` and `Check Out Date`, reshape by [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), so in last step is possible subtract by shifted columns by [`DataFrame.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html):

```
df['Check In Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Check In Date'])
df['Check Out Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Check Out Date'])


g = df.groupby('Number')
df = (df.assign(shitfted = g['Check Out Date'].shift(),
                stage = g['stage'].shift() + ' -> ' + df['stage'])
        .set_index(['stage','Number'])[['Check In Date','shitfted']]
        .unstack()
        .dropna()
      )
df = df['Check In Date'].sub(df['shitfted'])
print (df)
Number        1               2
stage                          
a -> b 04:02:00 1 days 05:43:00
b -> c 00:01:00 0 days 00:01:00
c -> d 00:00:00 0 days 00:01:00
```

EDIT:

For all combinations is used cross join with filtering by all combinations:

```
df['Check In Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Check In Date'])
df['Check Out Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Check Out Date'])

from  itertools import combinations

c = [f'{a} -> {b}' for a, b in (combinations(df['stage'].unique(), 2))]
print (c)
['a -> b', 'a -> c', 'a -> d', 'b -> c', 'b -> d', 'c -> d']

df = (df.merge(df, on='Number')
       .assign(stage = lambda x: x.pop('stage_x') + ' -> ' + x.pop('stage_y'))
       .query('stage in @c')
# df = df[df['stage'].isin(c)]
        .set_index(['stage','Number'])[['Check In Date_y','Check Out Date_x']]
        .unstack())
df = df['Check In Date_y'].sub(df['Check Out Date_x'])
print (df)
Number        1               2
stage                          
a -> b 04:02:00 1 days 05:43:00
a -> c 07:25:00 1 days 05:44:00
a -> d 07:25:00 1 days 08:03:00
b -> c 00:01:00 0 days 00:01:00
b -> d 00:01:00 0 days 02:20:00
c -> d 00:00:00 0 days 00:01:00
```

Comment: @ jezrael
It is possible to turn the result from day, hour, min, sec into second?

Comment: @Joanne - Sure, add `df = df['Check In Date'].sub(df['shitfted']).apply(lambda x: x.dt.total_seconds())`

Comment: @ jezrael - Thank you so much!!! One last question, it is possible to calculate all of the combination between stage? For example, a->b, a->c, a->d, b->c, b->d, c->d

Comment: @Joanne - Yes, need some time.

Comment: @Joanne - If some problem let me know, it should working well if not too many combinations.